# Questions on factor analysis and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible that $A*A^T=B*B^T$ while A and B have different ranks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax.  Please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one

Answer (score 1):

(My answer assumes that your matrices are $\in M(m \text{ x }n, \mathbb{R})$.)

No, it is not. The key here is to prove that $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(AA^T)$. For this, prove that $$A^TAx = 0 \iff Ax = 0\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

(then they have the same kernel, thus dimension formula provides that $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(A^TA)$ and thus $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(A^T) = \text{rank}(AA^T)$)

"$\Leftarrow$" is obvious. For "$\Rightarrow$" assume $A^TAx = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $$x^TA^TAx = 0 \implies (Ax)^TAx = 0 \implies \langle Ax,Ax \rangle = 0 \implies Ax = 0$$, where "$\langle\ , \rangle$" is the Euclidian scalar product (this doesn't hold for $\mathbb{C}$, for example, thus my assumption that the matrices are elements of $M(m \text{ x }n, \mathbb{R})$).

So now we have $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(AA^T)$, thus $AA^T \neq BB^T$ if $A$ and $B$ have different ranks.

Comment: What if $B$ is of a different size than $A$ but still $A^T A =B^T B $, say a $k \times n$ matrix? We still have equality of ranks, don't we?

Comment: @Roland I don't know if I understand your question correctly. If $B$ is of different size than $A$, then still rank of $B$ equals rank of $BB^T$ and rank of $A$ equals rank of $AA^T$. Then how can $AA^T = BB^T$? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Same rank, different sizes, but still $A^T A  = B^T B$: $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $B = (1)$. $A^TA = (1) = B^T B$.

Comment: But here rank of $A$ = 1 = rank of $B$. The questioner says "while A and B have different ranks".

Comment: Many Thanks! Another following up question: what if rank(A)=rank(B), but A and B are essentially different (it is like they don't have similar columns, say A[,j]!=c*B[,p] for all j and p where c is a constant). Is it possible that AA^T=BB^T?

Comment: @johnnycrab: Yes, that's what I meant with 'We still have equality of ranks'. Your result above still holds if we don't restrict ourselves to the case where both $A$ and $B$ are $m \times n$. Your reasoning is still fine if $A$ is $m \times n$ and $B$ is $k \times n$.

Comment: @Roland:Ah, now I understand what you meant! :) sorry. Yes, of course, maybe I should clarify this more .

Comment: @zpinthehouse: yes,  it is. For simple examples pick any two orthogonal n x n matrices for A and B.

Answer (score -1):

The rank of $A*A^T$ = $m*m$ Where $m$ is the no. of rows in $A$. So, as long as $A$ and $B$ have same no. of rows, it is possible

Comment: "The rank of $A∗A^T= m∗m$ Where $m$ is the no. of rows in $A$". How do you draw this conclusion?

Comment: The rank of $AA^T$ is always the same as the rank of $A$.